# Is it possible to add new predictions/autofill when using syntax in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

When using Overleaf you get quite helpful suggestions, like when you type in \beg it gives you the option to autofill the whole

```
\being{} 
\end{}
```

and even adds the contents of the first bracket into the second bracket.

However, there are some options that I use quite regularly, which while being compiled by Overleaf fine are not auto-filled, for example

```
\textsubscript{}
```

Is there a way to add new options to the prediction/autofill lists in Overleaf?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't possible at the moment! We'll add your vote to this feature though. (I'm a support personnel at Overleaf; you can also email suggestions or queries to welcome@overleaf.com)

Comment: @LianTzeLim that would be great! I am sure many people would find it useful

Comment: @LianTzeLim actually know that I have your attention, would it just be possible for Overleaf to add \textsubscript and \textsuperscript to the list of prediction/autofill