# Is it possible to add new predictions/autofill in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

For example, when I use the command (in Overleaf/ShareLaTex):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{some_graphic}
    \caption{some_caption}
    \label{fig:some_label}
\end{figure}
```

the `\includegraphics{}` comes without the `[]` parameter to change the size of the image, and `\begin{figure}` without the `[H]` option by default.

Is it possible to renew the command to make it default? By that I mean that when I type the `\begin{figure}` command it adds the `[H]` and `[h]` as well as `[width=\textwidth]` in the `\includegraphics` command, rather than making a global change in the preamble e.g.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79974/36296 for the default image width

Comment: off-topic: I would stay away from `[H]` - this is basically a guarantee for bad placement of images

Comment: To change the default floating specifier: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11342/36296

Comment: @samcarter I fully agree: `H` placement is wrong, particularly if one chooses to have all images as wide as the text width.

Comment: Thank you! I have always had this habit of using [H] to place images. I will look into that.

Comment: @Rune I would use `[htbp]` for images - this gives tex enough latitude to find the best possible position for you

Comment: What happens when you start typing `\begin{figure}` has nothing to do with latex, that is entirely up to whatever editor you us (and which is no information you shared with us)

Comment: @samcarter, sorry - I have just added to the question that I use Overleaf/ShareLaTex.

Comment: @Rune Thanks for the clarification - I voted to reopen, however the question might be off-topic. Because you are not looking for a tex solution but how to change the behaviour of overleaf, it might be better to ask their support than posting here.

Comment: @Samcarter, Thank you, I understand. I will ask the support. I was not aware if it was Overleaf related or not. I just thought I could do some "renewcommand".

Comment: @LianTze Lim The question is not about graphics, but about the autocomplete of the overleaf editor. Is it possible to change the autosuggestions?

Comment: Ah sorry, I had interpreted it as a `Gin` related question. No, autocompletion on Overleaf can't be customised like this at present. (So probably this question is not that relevant on tex.sx...)

Comment: @LianTzeLim I also thought about `Gin` at first, but after the edit the question took another direction :)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Maybe you can write a short answer that this is not possible at the moment? (I saw at least one similar (unanswered) question and if this one would have an answer, we could close the other as dupe)

Comment: related or even duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430461/is-it-possible-to-add-new-predictions-autofill-when-using-syntax-in-overleaf

Answer (score 7):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf)*

At present the code autocompletion options and blocks on Overleaf aren't user-customisable; sorry about this. If you think a particular snippet is useful for LaTeX users in general, you can send your suggestions to `welcome@overleaf.com`, thanks.

Comment: What about removing autocompletes? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479277/is-it-possible-to-remove-dynamically-added-autocompletions-from-overleaf

Comment: @Robino There's answer there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479291/226