# Is it possible to remove dynamically added autocompletions from Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, auto-completion

> This question is the converse to: [Is it possible to add new predictions/autofill in Overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479076/adding-width-textwidth-to-includegraphics)

In Overleaf LaTeX Editor, if you type some markup that the autocomplete does not recognise, it gets added to the autocomplete. 99% of the time this is great.

However, if you mistype something, such as `\bodl` instead of `\bold`, you will forever have `\bodl` come up as the first suggestion when inputting `\bo...`!

As the length of the document increases, and the number of typos goes up, the number of incorrect suggestions quickly starts to outweigh the benefit of the autocomplete, which is a real shame.

How can I remove these typos from the autocomplete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am correct Overleaf only uses commands that are already used in the document and does not suggest them anymore if there is no instance of the command left in the document.

The easiest way to remove faulty autocomplete entries would thus be to correct the commands on the places you have used them previously if you notice that Overleaf is suggesting faulty spelled commands (ctrl-F in the editor presents a replace all function to easily replace your misspelled commands at once if you have used the command many times already).

Comment: I have verified this to be the case. +1