# How to delete a command that was made while typing

Tags: overleaf

-So I mistyped \newline and a new command was made like \newlithen and now every time I type \new, the wrong command prompts up first and it is really starting to annoy me, anyone know how to delete a command. Thanks

Comment: [Is it possible to remove dynamically added autocompletions from Overleaf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479277/134144) might be related.

Comment: God damn, Can't believe I wrote it somewhere, Thanks!!