# Using bmatrix command

Tags: amsmath, overleaf

I have a rather strange question. when i am using `\begin{bmatrix}` it does not automatically come up with `\end{bmatrix}` as i have to type this manually. I am completely aware of how to use this command. Its just that it would save some time if `\end{bmatrix}` generates automatically when i open `\begin{bmatrix}`. Thanks for any help. I am using overleaf by the way.

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}

\begin{align*}
    A^* = A-BK &= \begin{bmatrix} -a_2 - b_2k_1 &1 - b_2k_2 &-b_2k_3\\ - a_1 - b_1k_1 &-b_1k_2 &1 - b_1k_3 \\ - a_0 - k_1 &-k_2 &-k_3 \end{bmatrix}\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 &1\\0 &1 &0\\ -1 &-3 &-3 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You always need to write begin and end of any environment, including `bmatrix`. However, some editors offers functionality to auto complete environments. For example. when you start to write `\begin{bmatrix}` it immediately add `\end{matrix}` and space between them, where you fill/write content of your matrix. This functionality has nothing to do with LaTeX. It require, that any environment had to be open (by `\bagin{...}`) and closed (by `\end{...}`).

Comment: any command completion is just a question about the editor so you are just asking about overleaf not a "by the way" side comment. According to this answer you can not add to the list of known commands but could put in a feature request https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479104

Comment: hmmm.. I see, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Command completion is purely a question about the editor not about latex.

As far as I can see Overleaf's editor does not "know" about bmatrix but it will pick up environments used earlier in the document, this screenshot shows a "later" `bmatrix` being added. As soon as you type `\begin`  the `\begin{bmatrix}` is offered which you can tab-complete at which point the closing `\end{bmatrix}` is added.

[image]

Note `\begin{bmatrix}...env` in the menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer on this