# How to edit a command autocomplete template in Overleaf?

Tags: macros, overleaf

In Overleaf, commands such as `\begin{figure}` and `\begin{table}` will automatically add a template after using the auto-complete option, such as:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

My question is if it is possible to change these templates?
For example, I want to use `\begin{tabularx}` instead, and put the `\caption` above the table.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) This sounds more like a question for the Overleaf support than for this site.

Comment: @campa Thanks for the welcome! I also found a duplicate question on autofill blocks here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479104/277575. Should I just remove my question, as it might be off-topic for this site as well?

Comment: No need to remove, as you've found a duplicate yourself. I've marked the question as duplicate, you can "accept" that.